# Chrome Devtools become grayed out while debugging for specific JS file

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

while debugging 3rd party code in Chrome DevTools one file became gray and I couldn't debug it, see values or do any operation on the content.
it occurs in a specific file only.
[image]
why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

After digging I found the issue is:

```
this._slot.innerHTML += '...
```

apparently, the debugger doesn't like those things and disabled the whole file from debugging.

BTW, the code working with that type of "+=" but it so not the right way it fricking out the debugger.